# to_latex() does not feature to_string()'s justify parameter

Tags: python, pandas

From `to_string()`:

> justify : {‘left’, ‘right’}, default None
>   Left or right-justify the column labels. If None uses the option from the > print configuration (controlled by set_option), ‘right’ out of the box.

[To_latex()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_latex.html) doesnt feature such a parameter. What's a valid alternative?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `column_format` argument.

```
import io

import pandas as pd


raw_df = io.StringIO("""\
  id1  id2  weights
0   a    2a   144.0
1   a    2b   52.5
2   b    2a   2.0
3   b    2e   1.0
""")
df = pd.read_csv(raw_df, delim_whitespace=True)

print(df.to_latex())

# Output:
# 
# \begin{tabular}{lllr}
# \toprule
# {} & id1 & id2 &  weights \\
# \midrule
# 0 &   a &  2a &    144.0 \\
# 1 &   a &  2b &     52.5 \\
# 2 &   b &  2a &      2.0 \\
# 3 &   b &  2e &      1.0 \\
# \bottomrule
# \end{tabular}

print(df.to_latex(column_format='rrrr'))

# Output:
# 
# \begin{tabular}{rrrr}
# \toprule
# {} & id1 & id2 &  weights \\
# \midrule
# 0 &   a &  2a &    144.0 \\
# 1 &   a &  2b &     52.5 \\
# 2 &   b &  2a &      2.0 \\
# 3 &   b &  2e &      1.0 \\
# \bottomrule
# \end{tabular}
```

Comment: I guess this works, but it feels somewhat odd as I have to dynamically generate the string based on how many columns I'm showing. If there's really nothing else, I'll take it.

Comment: That's not too bad though: `column_format='r' * len(df.columns)`.

Comment: @FooBar if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.